# Why is reflexivity of the equivalence relation required to show that $(a,a^\prime)\mapsto a-a^\prime$ is a mapping?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

This regards [BBFSK](https://mitpress.mit.edu/contributors/h-behnke) V-I page 108,etc.

Integers are introduced to provide solutions to equations of the form

$$a=c+a^{\prime}\text{ where }a\le a^{\prime},$$

where $a,a^\prime$ are natural numbers.

The "mapping" $(a,a^\prime)\mapsto a-a^\prime$ gives the notation for expressing integers.  I put *mapping* in quotes because they latter say we need additional proof in order to call this a mapping.  At this point, there is no definition of subtraction. The string of characters $a-a^\prime$ is merely a composite symbol.

It is assumed that the associative, commutative and cancellation laws established for natural numbers apply to equations involving both integers and natural numbers. Using  $a=(a-a^\prime)+a^\prime$ and $b=(b-b^\prime)+b^\prime$ which characterize $a-a^\prime$ and $b-b^\prime$, we obtain

$$(b-b^\prime)+b^\prime+a=b+(a-a^\prime).$$

Form that, by cancellation we establish

$$b-b^\prime=a-a^\prime\iff a+b^\prime=a^\prime+b.$$

This motivates our defining the relation between pairs

$$\left(a,a^{\prime}\right)\bumpeq\left(b,b^{\prime}\right)\iff a+b^{\prime}=a^{\prime}+b.$$

Integer addition is provisionally defined by

$$\left(a-a^{\prime}\right)+\left(b-b^{\prime}\right)=\left(a+b\right)-\left(a^{\prime}+b^{\prime}\right).$$

Which is seen to be a homomorphism.

> [O]ur task consists of constructing, together with its set of images, a homomorphism $f$ of the set of pairs of natural numbers in such a way that pairs $(a,a^\prime)$, $(b,b^\prime)$ have the same image if and only if $(a,a^\prime)\bumpeq(b,b^\prime),$ with $\bumpeq$ defined as above.

The authors then stipulate that equality is **defined** as suggested by the motivating discussion.  That is

$$b-b^\prime=a-a^\prime\iff a+b^\prime=a^\prime+b$$

becomes the provisional definition of integer equality.  They then proceed to show that this definition satisfies the necessary requirements.

To show that $\bumpeq$ is an equivalence relation, reflexivity and comparativity

$$\left(a,a^{\prime}\right)\bumpeq\left(a,a^{\prime}\right),$$

$$\left(a,a^{\prime}\right)\bumpeq\left(c,c^{\prime}\right)\land\left(b,b^{\prime}\right)\bumpeq\left(c,c^{\prime}\right)\implies\left(a,a^{\prime}\right)\bumpeq\left(b,b^{\prime}\right),$$

are then shown. Reflexivity follows easily from

$$\left(a,a^{\prime}\right)\bumpeq\left(a,a^{\prime}\right)\iff a+a^{\prime}=a^{\prime}+a.$$

Comparativity is shown as follows:

$$\left(a,a^{\prime}\right)\bumpeq\left(c,c^{\prime}\right)\iff a+c^{\prime}=a^{\prime}+c\text{ and,}$$

$$\left(b,b^{\prime}\right)\bumpeq\left(c,c^{\prime}\right)\iff b+c^{\prime}=b^{\prime}+c$$

$$\implies a+c^{\prime}+b^{\prime}=a^{\prime}+c+b^{\prime}.$$

After both of these properties are verified the authors write

> Only after [reflexivity] is proved is it clear that [$(a,a^\prime)\mapsto a-a^\prime$] is actually a mapping: from $\left(a,a^{\prime}\right)=\left(b,b^{\prime}\right)$ it follows that $a-a^{\prime}=b-b^{\prime}.$

Why is proof of the reflexivity of $\bumpeq$ required in order to conclude that $(a,a^\prime)\mapsto a-a^\prime$ is a mapping?

I found the following speculation in my notes: Consider this summary of the task at hand: The goal is to construct, together with its set of images, the homomorphism $f(a,a^\prime)=a-a^\prime$ of the set of pairs of natural numbers in such a way that pairs $(a,a^\prime)$ and $(b,b^\prime)$ have the same image if and only if $(a,a^\prime)\bumpeq(b,b^\prime)$. The image of $(a,a^\prime)$ is written $(a-a^\prime)$. So, in order for $(a,a^\prime)\mapsto a-a^\prime$ to actually be a mapping, we must have an image equal to itself.  **Is this correct?**

This is a [PDF save of my Mathematica notebook](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pgtvNoyfr0BWb94p4V_S60h8AWkf4MGY/view?usp=sharing) recording my observations while studying this subject.  It is a work-in-progress, and written for my own use.  I have recorded things as I understand them, and have added my own elaborations and further observations.  These may, of course, misrepresent the original source.  Currently the section under discussion in this post begins on page 17.  It is the chapter titled **BBFSK IB-1.2 The Integers.**

Comment: Can you say _exactly_ how "$a-a'$" is defined?  Based on what you have written, it appears that the assertion you are asking about is simply wrong.  But you may be misrepresenting some important details.

Comment: It also may matter how equality is defined in this text.  It seems the meaning of equality here may be somewhat nonstandard.

Comment: Although I do not know this text (and cannot access it from the link provided), I do know that in other texts such as Tao's "Analysis" the string $a-a'$ is intended to denote the equivalence class of the pair $(a,a')$ under the equivalence relation defined in the post (to be more formally correct, one should distinguish the "minus sign" in the notation $a-a'$ in some special way, perhaps by making it big and red). To put this another way, the map $(a,a') \mapsto a-a'$ should literally be thought of associating to $(a,a')$ its equivalence class.

Comment: The role of reflexivity thus becomes its usual role: in proving that $(a,a')$ is equivalent to $(b,b')$ if and only if $(a,a')$ and $(b,b')$ are in the same equivalence class, reflexivity is needed to cover the case that $(b,b')=(a,a')$. Having said that, I cannot make much sense of the quote you provided from the text you are reading.

Comment: @EricWofsey I added more context, but I'm not sure how helpful it will be.

Comment: @LeeMosher It would be inappropriate to provide a link to any bootleg copies available on the Internet.  Since I have purchased these volume multiple times, I feel no guilt in posessing an electronic version for personal use.  Since the books are out of print, they may be in the public domain.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am fairly certain the intent is that in order for a mapping of algebraic objects to have any meaning, there must be, at a minimum, a definition of self-equivalency. This is not spelled out explicitly in the section on relations, but is seems to be a reasonable inference.

Or, if for some reason we don't want reflexivity, we, at least need *some* condition to test in determining membership in the target domain.  That is, the elements of the domain are those objects which satisfy the algebra.  If there are no relations established, there is no predicate, or propositional form.

Answer (score 1):

The statement you are asking about only makes sense as a vague intuitive statement and is not literally correct.  You should understand it merely as an observation that the condition $x=y \implies f(x)=f(y)$ which is sometimes thought of as characterizing a function ends up corresponding to the reflexive property of $\bumpeq$, if you define $f(a,a')=a-a'$ and then interpret "$a-a'=b-b'$" as a shorthand for $(a,a')\bumpeq(b,b')$.

It is not actually an accurate statement if you dig into the weeds of how to define and prove everything precisely, though.  First of all, it is extremely misleading to think of $x=y \implies f(x)=f(y)$ as the definition of what it means for $f$ to be a function.  If you do not yet know that $f$ gives one output for each input, then the symbols $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ are meaningless (since, for instance, if you are treating $f$ as a set of ordered pairs, $f(x)$ is defined as "the unique $z$ such that $(x,z)\in f$ which is only meaningful if such a $z$ exists and is unique).  So, you cannot even evaluate the truth of a statement like $f(x)=f(y)$ unless you already know $f$ is a function.

Second of all, we should *not* interpret "$a-a'=b-b'$" as a shorthand for $(a,a')\bumpeq(b,b')$.  If we are going to eventually make a rigorous definition instead of the non-rigorous motivational use of the symbol $a-a'$ which started the discussion, we need to give a precise definition of $a-a'$, and then the meaning of $a-a'=b-b'$ will come from that definition and the usual notion of equality.  Note in particular then that it will be immediate that $(a,a')=(b,b')$ implies $a-a'=b-b'$ and that $(a,a')\mapsto a-a'$ is a function by the usual substitution property of equality; this has absolutely nothing to do with the reflexivity of $\bumpeq$.  In particular, the most natural way to do so is to *define* $a-a'$ to refer to the equivalence class of $(a,a')$ with respect to $\bumpeq$: that is, $a-a'$ is defined as the set $\{(b,b'):(a,a')\bumpeq (b,b')\}$.  Once you have proved that $\bumpeq$ is an equivalence relation, then it follows that $a-a'=b-b'$ iff $(a,a')\bumpeq(b,b')$ (but this is a theorem, not the definition of "$a-a'=b-b'$").

Comment: I believe it is a fair assessment to say equality is defined by $\left(b,b^{\prime}\right)\bumpeq\left(c,c^{\prime}\right)$ $\iff b+c^{\prime}=b^{\prime}+c$ $ \iff a-a^{\prime}=b-b^{\prime}$. That the first form means the same thing as the second follows from the requirement that addition be associative, commutative and cancellative.  That's pretty much how $a-a^\prime$ is defined.  It's that thing that satisfies the algebraic requirements.

Comment: That's not actually a definition, though.  How do you know that "that thing that satisfies the algebraic requirements" actually exists?  You have to actually construct it somehow.

Comment: That's what the discussion is about.  In a sense I jumped the gun by offering a definition of integer addition.  At that point it is only motivational.  The definition of equality is constructed to satisfy the algebra. After proving that $\bumpeq$ is an equivalence relation, they explain how this establishes equivalence classes of pairs. They then prove that addition, defined as I presented it, is consistent with $\bumpeq$.  Then it's on to defining multiplication as endomorphisms of the module (Abelian group) of the integers.

Comment: But we don't _define_ equality.  At least in the standard foundations of mathematics, equality is a primitive notion.  Instead, we first define what $a-a'$ means, and then we will know what equality means for it.  (Of course, we should choose our definition so that equality ends up being what we want, but the point is that it's $a-a'$ which we define, not equality.)

Comment: The primitive equality is the set equality of equivalence classes.  So "defining equality" means establishing equivalence classes.  The book actually calls these residue classes in this context.

Answer (score 0):

In general, when we establish a function, if we can have inputs that are "the same" but have different forms, we need to check that the function is well defined, meaning that the function takes the same value on different forms of a given input.

Another example of this you may have seen in abstract algebra would be a function on a quotient group. Say you have a function on cosets, written $a + N$, where the function is defined only in terms of $a$. You would need to check that your choice of representative of the coset does not change the value of the function.

Verifying reflexivity of your equivalence relation is the same as making sure the map is well defined and is therefore a map at all. (Which is, I believe, what you were getting at in your edit.)

Comment: This is a common story but does not appear to be what is going on here.  The equivalence classes here seem to be the codomain of the function, not the domain.

Comment: @EricWofsey My thought was that the reflexivity of the relation means that if (a,a') = (b,b'), then (a,a') and (b,b') are in the same equivalence class, from which it follows that a-a' = b-b', showing that the map is well defined. Am I off base?

Comment: But if $(a,a')=(b,b')$, then $(a,a')$ and $(b,b')$ are not "different forms" at all: they are literally the same thing!  Assuming you know that $a-a'$ has any meaning at all, it follows immediately that $a-a'$ and $b-b'$ are the same, just by the substitution property of equality.  This has nothing to do with reflexivity.

Comment: Now if the definition of $a-a'$ is "the equivalence class of $(a,a')$ with respect to $\bumpeq$" and "equivalence class" is only defined for an equivalence relation, then you need to first prove that $\bumpeq$ is an equivalence relation, in order for $a-a'$ to even be defined.  But this still does not really have anything to do with reflexivity in particular.

Comment: In any case, it is highly misleading to suggest that this situation is analogous to how we need to check that a map is well-defined when our domain consists of equivalence classes.

Comment: @asterac I don't believe your answer is correct.  Nor do I think it is incorrect.  That is, you seem to have captured the essence of the matter.  I need to review the section on relations in the chapter on foundational concepts before I can decide if it is applicable, and if so, how to explain the situation in those terms.  But, roughly speaking, the mapping in question is from the domain of pairs of natural numbers to a domain of objects which satisfy a certain algebra.  In order for there to be an algebra, at all, there must be some kind of equivalence.